# Многоуровневый ExpandableListView android studio

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Реализован ExpandableListView

Цель - сделать трехуровневый список для каталога товаров

В моём случай список имеет двухуровневый

Как показано в скриншоте при нажатие на  каждый элемент  нужно чтобы  открывался новый список с категориями товаров

Как мне реализовать метод построения многоуровневого списка?

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {






    String[] groups = new String[]{"Автоаксессуары", "Домашний текстиль",
            "Ароматизаторы", "Бытовая химия", "Электротехника и мобильные аксессуары", "Товары для детей", "Туризм и Рыбалка",
            "Галантерея", "Акустические системы", "Дача и Сад", "Инструменты", "Канцелярские товары", "Подарки", "Освещение и видеонаблюдение",
            "Посуда и кухонные принадлежности", "Продукты", "Сантехника и товары для ванной комнаты", "Спорт и отдых", "Мобильные аксессуары и инструменты",
            "Новогодние товары", "Товары для животных", "Хозтовары", "Профессиональные, чистящие средства ЭКО\"OMINEREL\""};
    
    String[] car_accessories = new String[]{"FM Модуляторы", "Автозвук", "Автомагнитолы", "Автомобильный свет, фонари, лампы переноски"
            , "Автохимия", "Автоэлектроника", "Антенны автомобильные", "Ароматизаторы", "Безопасность и комфорт",
            "Видеорегистраторы", "Держатели", "Коврики на панель", "Внутрисалонные аксессуары", "Компрессоры и насосы автомобильные", "Пылесосы автомобильные"
            , "Тросы буксировочные, стяжки груза", "Внешние декоративные элементы", "Радар-детекторы", "Уход за автомобилем",
            "Щетки стеклоочистителя", "Домкраты", "Ковры автомобильные", "Краски и принадлежности для кузовного ремонта", "Лебёдки, Тали",
            "Обслуживание и техосмотр", "Оплетки NEW GALAXY", "Органайзеры, сетки и сумки", "Отдых и туризм авто", "ПнАксессуарыевматические насадки",
            "Провода пусковые", "Разветвлители прикуривателя", "Сезонный ассортимент", "Хомуты NORMA и РОС", "Чехлы и накидки автомобильные"};

    String[] Home_textiles = new String[]{"Пледы. Покрывала. Декор", "Полотенца махровые", "Постельное белье", "Скатерти, салфетки", "Текстиль для сна",
            "Кухонный текстиль", "Шторы, жалюзи и аксессуары к ним", "Сезонный Электротехника и мобильные аксессуарытекстиль"};


    String[] Accessories = new String[]{"Ароматизаторы для авто", "Ароматизаторы для дома"};


    String[] Household_chemicals = new String[]{"Бумажная и ватная продукция, антисептики", "Детская косметика и гигиена",
            "Подарочные наборы", "Предметы женской гигиены", "Принадлежности для бритья и депиляции", "Средства для ванн и душа", "Средства для стирки и уход за бельем",
            "Средства от насекомых", "Уход за волосами", "Уход за кожей лица и тела", "Уход за полостью рта", "Чистящие средства",
            "Профессиональные, чистящие средства ЭКО\"OMINEREL\"", "Средства по уходу за одеждой и обувью"};

    String[] Electrical_engineering_and_mobile_accessories = new String[]{"Стекла,чехлы", "Электроника", "Элементы питания", "Источники света", "Мобильные и компьютерные аксессуары", "Электронные устройства"};


    String[] Products_for_children = new String[]{"Активные игры", "Игротека", "Игрушки для девочек", "Игрушки для малышей", "Игрушки для мальчиков",
            "Книги, раскраски, наклейки, обучающие материалы", "Конструкторы",
            "Мебель и хранение, прогулки, путешествия", "Мягкая игрушка", "Настольные игры, пазлы", "Творчество",
            "Продукты", "Радиоуправляемый транспорт и прочая игрушка"};


    String[] tourism_and_fishing = new String[]{"Барбекю и костровое хозяйство", "Кемпинг и туризм", "Товары для летней рыбалки", "Бинокли", "Зимняя рыбалка", "Наборы для выживания",
            "Рации", "Фонари", "Складные ножи", "Фонари со светодиодами"};

    String[] Haberdashery = new String[]{"Аксессуары", "Банные принадлежности", "Бельевой трикотаж, одежда, обувь",
            "Визаж, маникюр, педикюр", "Кожгалантерея", "Коллекции", "Косметика, парфюмерия",
            "Пакеты для покупателей", "Парафармацевтика", "Сезонная галантерея", "Чулочно-носочные изделия,",
            "Швейная галантерея"};

    String[] acoustic_systems = new String[]{"Активные колонки", "Микрофоны", "Напольные колонки",
            "Наушники, гарнитуры", "Портативные колонки", "Радиоприемники"};

    String[] Dacha_and_garden = new String[]{"Все для домашних растений", "Все для рассады", "Одежда и обувь для сада",
            "Полив", "Садовый декор", "Садовый инвентарь", "Семена, грунты, удобрения", "Освещение для сада", "Садовая техника",
            "Средства бытовой защиты", "Средства защиты"};

    String[] Tools = new String[]{"Автоинструмент", "Все для отделочных работ", "Замки", "Измерительный инструмент",
            "Клейкие ленты, скотчи, пленки", "Малярно-штукатурный инструмент", "Молотки и топоры",
            "Оснастка для электроинструмента", "Слесарный инструмент", "Средства индивидуальной защиты", "" +
            "Шарнирно - губцевый инструмент", "Шлифовальный инструмент.Напильники", "Электроинструмент",
            "Инструменты, прочее", "Отвертки", "Сопутствующие товары", "Столярный инструмент", "Строительная химия",
            "Щетки проволочные,металлические", "Фурнитура"};

    String[] Stationery = new String[]{"Блокноты, записные книжки, ежедневники", "Бумага, бумажная продукция для офиса",
            "Бумажная продукция для школы", "Забавная канцелярия", "Офисные товары", "Письменные и чертежные принадлежности", "" +
            "Товары для творчества", "Товары для учебы", "Школьный текстиль и аксессуары"};

    String[] Present = new String[]{"Ароматерапия", "Всё для праздника", "Игры и досуг", "Подарочная упаковка",
            "Предметы интерьера", "Свечи, светильники, подсвечники", "Фоторамки,фотоальбомы", "Цветы и фрукты искусственные",
            "Часы и будильники", "Шкатулки и ключницы", "Пасхальные товары", "Функциональные сувениры"};

    String[] Lighting_and_video_surveillance = new String[]{"Домофоны и СКУД", "Освещение (компоненты", "Видеонаблюдение",
            "Инструменты", "Праздничный ассортимент", "Источники питания", "Кабели и провода", "Профиль", "Электрика",
            "Прочее", "Светильники для помещений", "Светильники уличные", "Световая реклама", "Управление освещением"};


    String[] Crockery_and_kitchen_utensils = new String[]{"Доски разделочные", "Ножи кухонные аксессуары",
            "Посуда для приготовления", "Сезонные предложения", "Столовая посуда и предметы сервировки", "Термосы и фляжки", "" +
            "Товары для кухни", "Товары для хранения продуктов", "TRAMONTINA Ножи", "Посуда из нержавеющей стали Индия", "Столовые приборы из нержавеющей стали"};


    String[] Products = new String[]{"Бакалея", "Вода", "Жевательные резинки, драже", "Колбасные изделия",
            "Кондитерские изделия", "Консервация", "Молочные продукты", "Снеки(чипсы, сухарики, кукурузные палочки", "" +
            "Сок,нектар", "Хлеб, хлебобулочные изделия", "Чай, кофе, какао"};

    String[] Plumbing_and_bathroom_products = new String[]{"Аксессуары для ванной", "Душевое оборудование", "Инженерная сантехника",
            "Комплектующие для сантехники", "Смесители"};

    String[] Sports_and_recreation = new String[]{"BestWay Летний сезон", "INTEX Летний сезон", "Зимние виды спорта", "Летние виды спорта",
            "Отдых, путешествия", "Фитнес. Йога", "BestWay", "INTEX", "Звездный спорт"};

    String[] Mobile_accessories_and_tools = new String[]{"Аккумуляторы для телефонов", "Держатели POP-SOCKET, настольные держатели",
            "Мультиинструменты для точных работ", "Портативные зарядные устройства", "Товары для блогера"};

    String[] Christmas_goods = new String[]{"Гирлянды евростандарт", "Декоративные елки и хвойный декор",
            "Дождик, мишура, украшения из фольги", "Ели искусственные", "Карнавальные аксессуары", "Карнавальные костюмы и головные уборы",
            "Мягкая игрушка новогодняя", "Новогодние Кросс-коллекции", "Новогодний интерьер", "Подарочная упаковка НГ", "Символ года",
            "Стеклянная игрушка", "Сувениры новогодние", "Украшения декоративные", "Шары и наборы шаров", "Электрогирлянды"};

    String[] Goodsforpets = new String[]{"Корма для животных", "Амуниция для животных", "Гигиена животных", "Игрушки для животных"};


    String [] household_goods = new String [] {"Интерьер для дома","Кухонные аксессуары и принадлежности","Товары для ванной",
            "Товары для дома и сада","Товары для уборки","Товары по уходу за одеждой и обувью"};

    String [] Professional_cleaning_products = new String [] {"Профессиональные, чистящие средства ЭКО\"OMINEREL\""};

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;
    TextView text_all_catagory;
    Map<String, String> m;
    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    ExpandableListView elvMain;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
        
        elvMain = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explistview);
        elvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;
        
        // коллекция для элементов одной группы
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;
        // общая коллекция для коллекций элементов
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;
        // в итоге получится childData = ArrayList<childDataItem>

        // список атрибутов группы или элемента
        Map<String, String> m;
        ExpandableListView elvMain;
        

        // заполняем коллекцию групп из массива с названиями групп
        groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String group : groups) {
            // заполняем список атрибутов для каждой группы
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("Автоаксессуары", group); // имя компании
            groupData.add(m);

        }
        // список атрибутов групп для чтения
        String groupFrom[] = new String[] {"Автоаксессуары", "Домашний текстиль",
                "Ароматизаторы", "Бытовая химия", "Электротехника и мобильные аксессуары", "Товары для детей", "Туризм и Рыбалка",
                "Галантерея", "Акустические системы", "Дача и Сад", "Инструменты", "Канцелярские товары", "Подарки", "Освещение и видеонаблюдение",
                "Посуда и кухонные принадлежности", "Продукты", "Сантехника и товары для ванной комнаты", "Спорт и отдых", "Мобильные аксессуары и инструменты",
                "Новогодние товары", "Товары для животных", "Хозтовары", "Профессиональные, чистящие средства ЭКО\"OMINEREL\""};
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты групп
        int groupTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        
        // создаем коллекцию для коллекций элементов
        childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();
        
        // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
        for (String phone : car_accessories){
            String car = "";

            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone); // название телефона
            childDataItem.add(m);
            //HashMap
        }
        // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        // создаем коллекцию элементов для второй группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone : Home_textiles) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
        // создаем коллекцию элементов для третьей группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone :Accessories) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
        
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone:Household_chemicals) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone:Electrical_engineering_and_mobile_accessories) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Products_for_children) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);


        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: tourism_and_fishing) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);


        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Haberdashery) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
        
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone:  acoustic_systems) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Dacha_and_garden) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Tools) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);


        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Stationery) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Present) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Lighting_and_video_surveillance ) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Crockery_and_kitchen_utensils ) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);


        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Products ) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Plumbing_and_bathroom_products ) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);


        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Sports_and_recreation) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Mobile_accessories_and_tools) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone: Christmas_goods) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone:  Goodsforpets) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);


        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone:household_goods ) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);



        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone:Professional_cleaning_products ) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
        

        // список атрибутов элементов для чтения
        String childFrom[] = new String[] {"phoneName"};
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты элементов
        int childTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                childData,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                childFrom,
                childTo);

        elvMain = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explistview);
        elvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




}
```

catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <ExpandableListView
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:transitionGroup="true"
        android:id="@+id/explistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ExpandableListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: По идее без боли, страданий и лютых костылей ничего не получится. Тем более с использованием стандартного адаптера. Правильным решением будет использование RecyclerView со своим адаптером. При нажатии на элемент списка надо будет добавлять/удалять элементы из списка.

Comment: В смысле "Реализован ExpandableListView", может быть использован?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
 Благодарю за ответ